# How to programmatically change password for a user without interactive prompt in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, passwd

I'm trying to change the password for user foo with user bar by calling a shell command. But I have some problems.

I can do this to send a password to sudo

```
$ echo sudopw | sudo -S ls
```

And this to change password:

```
$ echo foo:newpw | sudo chpasswd
[sudo] password for bar: sudopw
```

This changes the password for user foo to newpw, but it forces me to enter the sudo password manually.

The problem is that I cannot see how to combine these things. I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$ echo sudopw | sudo -S echo foo:newpw | chpasswd 
chpasswd: Permission denied.
chpasswd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
[sudo] password for bar: [bar@host]$
```

I did manage to do it like this:

```
echo sudopw | echo -e "newpw\nnewpw" | sudo passwd dummy
```

But when I tried it like this it asks for password again.

```
os.system('echo sudopw | echo -e "newpw\nnewpw" | sudo passwd dummy')
```

I have found numerous answers on how to send the password to `sudo <cmd>` where cmd does not require any additional input. But I really cannot solve the situation of BOTH sending input to cmd AND sending the password to sudo from a python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sudo command without password.

```
$ sudo visudo
```

If you run python with XXX user, then please add the following line.

```
XXX ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

After, you can use `$ sudo chpasswd` command without password.

Comment: Yes, I know, but unfortunately that was not an option for me.

Comment: Please check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If visudo is not your option, then please try the following

```
$ echo 'sudopassword
foo:newpassword' | sudo -S /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Or

```
$ echo -e "sudopassword\nfoo:newpassword" | sudo -S /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and my last snippet in the question?

Comment: Of course. Please try echo -e "sudopassword\nfoo:newpw" | sudo -S chpasswd

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it. I want to emphasize that this solution might have security flaws and may not be a suitable choice for everybody. In my case, it should only be run once, and anyone who could take advantage of any flaws in this code have already come way to far.

```
r = Popen(('mkpasswd', '-m', 'sha-512', new_password), stdout=PIPE)
shadow = r.communicate()[0].strip()

proc = Popen(['sudo', '-S', '-k', 'usermod', '-p', shadow, 'foo'], 
             stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(sudo_password + b'\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is caching the password for a short while, you may try to make 2 different calls, one to provide password to `sudo`: something like `sudo ls` works just fine, then you call the second command, which will not require the password for `sudo`, just the input you need to change the user's password.